# Some tagging questions

Tags: discussion, tagging

In total defiance of Stack Exchange rules, here are eleven questions compressed into one: what to do about the following tags?

- <strike>[look-and-feel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/look-and-feel): What does this tag mean?</strike> (removed)
- [foreach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foreach): used for the PGF command. Merge into [loops](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loops)?
- [external-file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/external-file), [write-file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/write-file), [auxiliary-files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auxiliary-files), [filesystem-access](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filesystem-access): Should those be combined in some way?
- [file-lookup](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-lookup): What does this tag mean?
- [tex-history](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tex-history): merge into [tex-general](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tex-general)?
- <strike>[format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/format): merge into [formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formatting)? Does anyone have a good description of these tags?</strike> (renamed to [format-files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/format-files))
- <strike>[web](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web): same as [online](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online)?</strike> (retagged so that only questions about WEB are tagged [web](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web))
- [source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source): what does it mean (we also have [highlighting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/highlighting) and [syntax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax))?
- [highlighting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/highlighting): should it be renamed to [syntax-highlighting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax-highlighting)?
- [preamble](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/preamble): do we need it, and if so how do we ensure that it is used more consistently?

Comment: +1 for {foreach} used for the PGF command. Merge into {loops}?

Answer (score 6):

My opinions:

- [look-and-feel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/look-and-feel): meaningless, for example [typography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography), [page-design](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/page-design) or [book-design](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-design) would be more appropriate.
- [foreach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foreach): perhaps change into [for-loops](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/for-loops). Besides PGF, there's the [`forloop`](http://ctan.org/pkg/forloop) package. Not merging into [loops](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loops) preserves the ability to distinguish it from `\whiledo` loops.
- [external-file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/external-file), [write-file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/write-file), [auxiliary-files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auxiliary-files), [filesystem-access](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filesystem-access) Yes, in some way. [auxiliary-files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auxiliary-files) should not be touched. Merge [external-file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/external-file) and [filesystem-access](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filesystem-access). [write-file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/write-file) doesn't cover read access.
- [file-lookup](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-lookup) is for `kpsewhich` and `kpathsea` in general.
- [tex-history](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tex-history): I would not merge into [tex-general](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tex-general), since history doesn't mean TeX code.
- [format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/format): *merge into [formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formatting)?* I guess [formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formatting) is pretty useless, we could get rid of it. [format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/format) could mean [format-files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/format-files) (fmt)
- [web](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web): see Martins answer. I would reserve that for the WEB language, questions about online/html should be retagged.
- [source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source) is pretty vague. I suggest merging [source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source) and [code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code) to [source-code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-code).
- [highlighting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/highlighting): *should it be renamed into [syntax-highlighting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax-highlighting)?* one could ask about highlighting words in normal text, so it doesn't need to mean syntax.

Comment: Making [tag:foreach] a synonym of a newly created [tag:for-loops] sounds sensible. So does [tag:format-files]. [tag:formatting] has evolved into a sort of catch-all tag, sorting that out is probably a bigger project (we could do that after the [tag:floats] project). [tag:highlighting] is currently almost exclusively used for syntax highlighting, hence the suggestion. Maybe add [tag:emphasizing] (would also cover beamer's alert and similar)?

Comment: For the WEB language, a tag {WEB} (capitalized) would reduce misapprehension.

Comment: @lockstep: uppercase characters are not allowed in tags.

Comment: Dang. Yes, it seemed *too* easy ...

Answer (score 5):

The [web](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web) tag seems to be used of WWW related posts, which should be retagged to [online](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online) and also for Knuth's WEB programming language.

See also this [short discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=559489#559489) in the tex.sx chat.

Comment: Maybe rename to [tag:web-programming] or something similar, that makes it more obvious what the tag is about?

Comment: I think {web-programming} (the `[tag:` syntax doesn't work in comments) might still be confused by users. What is with {web-language}?

Comment: @Caramdir: I guess Martin's right: Although I liked your idea at the first sight, many people will still think of "the web" when they see {web-programming}.

Comment: How about [tangled-web] for the Knuthian web?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source) I see six uses.  Two are about the source code of TeX the program and MetaFont the program.  Three are about typesetting code listings.  One is about TeXShop.

We could reserve [source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source) for questions about TeX and friends source code.  The three about typesetting listings should probably be tagged with [code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code) or [listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listings) instead.  The one TeXShop question should probably not have a tag about source at all.

Answer (score 2):

Could a mod please rename [format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/format) to [format-files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/format-files), as Stefan suggested. I retagged the other questions in [format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/format) to more appropriate tags.

Comment: I renamed the tag.