# highlighting tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

The current [highlighting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/highlighting) tag has 399 questions.

Its current short description is:

- {highlighting} is about highlighting document elements. Use this tag in addition to other tags specifying what should be highlighted.

These are a mixture of questions about highlighting things in the output PDF and syntax highlighting in the source document.

There was some discussion of this 5 years ago here:

- [Some tagging questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1047/2693)

Since we have a lot of both sorts, but they really have nothing in common, I've created a new tag [syntax-highlighting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax-highlighting) to distinguish editor highlighting from other sorts. I've added the following tag wiki:

- Many editors are able to highlight TeX keywords and other document components with different colours within the source code. Use this tag in conjunction with the [editors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editors) tag and the tag for your specific editor to ask questions about modifying the syntax highlighting for your particular editor.

Unless there are some objections I think it makes sense to gradually split apart the two sorts of questions. I'll also adjust the [highlighting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/highlighting) tag accordingly.

Comment: One might argue that the tag {[tag:syntax-highlighting]} might be confused with the output of code as produced with `listings` or `minted` packages

Comment: @ChristianHupfer True. I'm not sure there's a good way around that except making the tag hint clear. (For those that actually read them...)

Comment: `editor-syntax-highlighting` ?

Comment: @cfr I think I'll go with the one I've proposed and see what happens.

Comment: Aren't the experienced users in charge of proper tagging? Takes just a few seconds and we can't expect the people new to LaTeX to tag correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Well, one possibility is to find a good word for "highlighting teh output not teh code" and ban [highlighting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/highlighting) completely; this would force people to choose one of the more specific tags and hopefully avoid using [highlighting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/highlighting) where [syntax-highlighting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax-highlighting) should be.

I suggest [highlighting-output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/highlighting-output), even though it's not optimal as a tag name.

Comment: I guess I'm also trying to minimize the amount of retagging.

Comment: I think a tag can be renamed and then the original name banned... of course by mod power, but we have so powerful people around us :-)